# Can't insert link before ul in table divider

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to insert a link into a specific place within a `<td>` element - just before a `<ul>` element. I'm able to prepend/append the whole `<td>` without a problem... but not to a specific element in it.

This is what I'm trying

```
var find = $("table.month tr td." + holiday_starts + "ul")
var add_person = $('</br><a href="#"><center>'+the_person+'</center></a>').insertBefore(find)
```

Which isn't working. (holiday_starts is a variable that appears in my td class)

I need to insert the link in here:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td class="holiday_starts_var">
            "some text"
            // WANT LINK IN HERE
            <ul>
            </ul>
            ...
```

Comment: @P.Joe, For `$('.holiday_starts_var')` you must use `.html()`.

Comment: The problem would have been faster to detect if OP had posted a [mcve] using the `<>` snippet editor

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your selector is incorrect

```
var find = $("table.month tr td." + holiday_starts + "ul")
```

Resulting string will be:

```
table.month tr td.holiday_starts_varul
```

Change to :

```
var find = $("table.month tr td." + holiday_starts + " ul")
```

Note the space before `ul`, that should fix your selector

Answer (score 3):

You need to use the correct selector to select child `ul`

```
$("table.month tr td." + holiday_starts + " ul")
                                          //^^ Space is important
```

instead of

```
$("table.month tr td." + holiday_starts + "ul")
```

Answer (score 3):

Your selector is wrong because your class name mixed with `ul`. There must be space after class name

```
   var find = $("table.month tr td." + holiday_starts + "ul")
```

Should be

```
var find = $("table.month tr td." + holiday_starts + " ul")
```

Answer (score 0):

This works for me after inserting the space before the UL in the selector and giving the table a class.

Next time please create a  [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

```js
var holiday_starts = "x", the_person="bla"
var $find = $("table.month tr td." + holiday_starts + " ul");
$('</br><a href="#"><center>' + the_person + '</center></a>').insertBefore($find)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="month">
  <tr>
    <td class="x">
      "some text" // WANT LINK IN HERE
      <ul><li>...</li>
      </ul>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="y">
      <ul>
      </ul>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```